# Select a range in Excel vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Using vbScript, I use the find method to search a named range for a cell value and select that item in the worksheet if the value is found.  What I need to do is select a range of cells starting with the "found" cell and extending to the top row in the column and from the found cell to the bottom of the column.  So, if my found cell is A15 then I want to select the range that is A14 through A1 and from A16 to the bottom of the column.  I've been kicking this can down the road far to long.  Can someone help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
EndCell = "A14" ' You of course have to find A14 using your search function   
Range("A1:"&EndCell).Select
```

Comment: I forgot to say that on each worksheet there are a minimum of 3 named ranges.  The cell I find, say A15 could be in a range the "top" of which may be A7 and the bottom A95. How do I convert a cell address like $A$11 to A11 or do I need to?

Answer (score -1):

```
Columns(FoundCell.Column).Select
```